# What happens when Murata re-writes a One Punch Man manga chapter?

Tags: one-punch-man

Ok, so I've read what I believe it was chapter 165 of One Punch Man manga and apparently Murata re-wrote it.  This isnt the first time it happened. I can't find the one which was re-written anymore, and apparently never happened events like

> Saitama and Garou sitting at a table. Neither Blast comments about Earth bending.

Are the old ones for sell somewhere or something?

What happens when Murata re-writes a One Punch Man manga chapter?

Comment: This might be lacking enough context to properly answer because we don't know what you've read. However, when enough chapters from a magazine (serialization) are collected into a book (tankobon), sometimes the mangaka may revise some of the content.